# How to make an i x j matrix with j in a loop of i/j

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Hi I try to make an i x j matrix and j increases firstly to i/j then i increases. Here is a toy example of 6 x 2 matrix. Is there any code to achieve this easily? Many thanks for your help!

```
Table[{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: for this example, why not `Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 3}], 1]` which gives what you show.

Comment: Also `Flatten[Array[{##} &, {2, 3}], 1]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Tuples`:

```
Tuples[{{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}]
```

Comment: Many thanks. This function works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
f[n1_, n2_] := Flatten[Table[{i , j}, {i, n2}, {j, n1/n2}], 1] /; (n1 > 0 && n2 > 0 && AllTrue[{n1, n2, n1/n2}, IntegerQ])
MatrixForm[f[6, 2]]
```

The part after the "/;" is to ensure that n1 and n2 can be used to create such a desired matrix.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! Your comment helps me learn how to define a function.